# How would you use a regular expression in an activerecord scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I hoping to use a regular expression in a scope.

scope :smith, where(:full_name => /(smith)/)            #names that include the word smith

Is this possible I've been trying different approaches to this and searched this site and others but to date I've been getting a variety of errors.

Note: :full_name is a database field.

Comment: is full_name a database field or a virtual field,  also what database are you using? does it support regex searches?

Comment: What database are you using.

Comment: Sqlite in development will likely use MySQL or Postgres in prod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if using postgresql you can do this:

```
 scope :smith, where('full_name ~ ?', 'smith')
```

sqlite you can see here  http://titusd.co.uk/2010/01/31/regular-expressions-in-sqlite/  for something that might work.  Have never tried it though.

Comment: This approach is throwing database syntax error. It apparently doesn't like the ~. SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "~": syntax error)

Comment: did you read the answer? the ~ is postgresql which supports regex.  SQLite as far as I know doesn't support regex, so you need to do the stuff in the link to kinda fake it.

Comment: I did. I guess I'm trying to hold out for a solution that tied to a particular database.  Thanks again.

Comment: i don't think you are going to get a solution then, since not all databases are created equal. If the underlaying database doesn't support regular expressions. faking them is kinda hard.  For the simple case above you can fake it with  like '%smith%'  which would return the same thing..